# Can Jooq simulate window functions in MySql

Tags: mysql, jooq

My company is using mysql as their database layer. We are creating very complex reports that will be much easier if MySql had Window functions. I couldnt find any where in the documentation that Jooq supports window functions for mysql. Just want to know if its possible to do this with Jooq. If not, will this feature be added later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pending feature request to emulate window functions on databases that do not support them: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1715

It will certainly not be part of jOOQ 3.10, though.

Most window functions can indeed be emulated using correlated subqueries, although native support is quite likely to be much faster.

Do note that [there is work on window functions being done for a future MySQL release](https://www.slideshare.net/DagHWanvik/sql-window-functions-for-mysql). In the meantime, perhaps you could run your complex reports on a different database, e.g. PostgreSQL.